# Hana SQL Logic needed

Tags: sql, hana

```
select  groupid,count(value) as x
from test_distinct_count
group by rollup (groupid);
```

This query gives output like :

[image]

What i need is to display the value 5 for all the groupids in a column say Total.
Something like this :

[image]

how can this be achieved using Hana Sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am from sql server background hope sum() over() will exist in Hana, try the below solution

```
create table #temp(groupid int,value int)

insert into #temp values(1,1)
insert into #temp values(1,1)
insert into #temp values(1,1)
insert into #temp values(2,2)
insert into #temp values(2,2)

select 
a.*,sum(x) over()/2 as Total
from (
select  groupid,count(value) as x
from #temp
group by rollup (groupid)
)a
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be following:

```
with grp as ( select  groupid, count(value) as x
              from test_distinct_count
              group by rollup (groupid) ),
     cnt as ( select count(value) as total from test_distinct_count )
select grp.groupid, grp.x, cnt.total from grp cross join cnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

create table #temp(groupid int,value int)

insert into #temp values(1,1)
insert into #temp values(1,1)
insert into #temp values(1,1)
insert into #temp values(2,2)
insert into #temp values(2,2)

select * from (
select groupid,count(value) as x
from #temp
group by rollup(groupid)
)a cross apply
(
select  count(value) as Total
from #temp
)b

Comment: Cross Apply Works best for your Scenario

Answer (score 0):

Do the window function first, then the rollup:

```
select groupid, count(value), max(total) as total
from (select groupid, value,
             sum(case when value is not null then 1 end) over () as total
      from test_distinct_count
      group by groupid
     ) t
group by rollup (groupid);
```

This is safer if you want to add more columns to the `group by`.